Pólya trees counted efficiently
The number of unlabeled rooted trees with n nodes is a fundamental sequence in graph theory and in discrete mathematics in general.
Some authors call these trees 'Polya trees'. The number of these trees is one of the 'core' sequences in the OEIS A000081.
A natural refinement of the enumeration asks how many of these trees have a given height. This is investigated in A034781 (has keyword 'nice').
In practice, a third sequence arises: one would like to know how many of these trees with a given number of vertices do not exceed a certain height. This sequence is to be implemented here.
Formally, we deviate a little from the presentation in A034781: We consider n vertices with n >= 0 (as is also done in A000081) and differentiate with respect to the level.
The level of a vertex is the number of vertices in the path from the root to the vertex (this is just one more than the depth of the vertex), and the level of the root is 1.
The enumeration can be written as a lower triangular matrix, where the row index indicates the number of vertices. So A000081 is found in the main diagonal.
0: [0]
1: [0, 1]
2: [0, 0, 1]
3: [0, 0, 1,  2]
4: [0, 0, 1,  3,  4]
5: [0, 0, 1,  5,  8,   9]

Task:
Write a function T(n, k) that implements the above matrix. It is about the efficiency of the algorithm. To do this, calculate the first b rows of the triangle:
Row(n) = [T(n, k) for k in 0..n],
Triangle(b) = [Row(n) for n in 0..b-1].

For b = 64 and b = 128, measure the time required t(b). The competition criterion is the quotient t(128)/t(64) [the smaller the better]; the computing time is unimportant.
Roughly speaking, the criterion measures by what the computing time multiplies when the number of rows doubles. The smallest quotient in a programming language wins.
Note: The function should be kept completely general and must not contain any instructions for special parameter values. Wait or sleep instructions are not allowed. The quotient a(n)/a(m) for two different values ​​n, m must represent the ratio of the execution times in a fair manner.
I wrote a reference implementation for Python. The quotient on my computer is 15.78; thus the computing time roughly increases by a factor of 2^4 when the number of rows is doubled.

This sounds like a nice problem. Unfortunately, an implementation could wait a million years before returning if the argument were 64, so that t(128)/t(64) would be tiny.

Well, maybe just ban sleep-or-equivalent functions. This is [tag:fastest-algorithm], after all...

[tag:fastest-algorithm] is scored on asymptotic time complexity. If you want to use real time measurements, that's [tag:fastest-code], but it does sound like your intent with the "scaling factor" scoring is an approximation of the former.

@Unrelated String Yes, that's right. I want to make the comparison criterion as meaningful as possible without talking about the tools used, but at the same time, practical enough to use without resorting to theoretical considerations or such silly measures as banning 'sleep'-functions.

I'm now changing the label to "fastest-code". If this does not improve the situation, I am happy to withdraw my proposal as unsuitable.

The criterion might need a little tweaking as I can get a better score by slowing down my t(64) code. Why not just use the wall clock time for t(128)? All challenges are per language so this shouldn't put off Python coders for example.

Python port

(this is in reference to your presumably since deleted comment on my answer; I'm sorry it took me so much time to respond but I am currently undergoing chemotherapy)

Python 3.8+,  ~ 8.3 - 11.5  ~ 6.8 - 10.9
Thanks to gsitcia for improving speed by extracting a memoised weighted tree count function and for providing a nice timing framework.
import functools


@functools.lru_cache(None)
def divisors(n):
    return [d for d in range(n, 0, -1) if n % d == 0]


@functools.lru_cache(None)
def divisor_weighted_tree_count(nodes, max_height):
    return sum(d * tree_count(d, max_height) for d in divisors(nodes))


@functools.lru_cache(None)
def tree_count(nodes, max_height):
    if nodes == 1:
        return int(max_height > 0)
    if max_height == 0:
        return 0
    next_height = max_height - 1
    return sum(
        tree_count(i, max_height) * divisor_weighted_tree_count(nodes - i, next_height)
        for i in range(1, nodes)
    ) // (nodes - 1)

Try it online! (The ratio at TIO is not as good as locally in Python 11 on Windows 11 for some reason, I used the latter for my headline ratio range.)
Here are the results of the same performance measuring as in the TIO code run six times locally (Python 3.11, Windows 11, AMD Ryzen 9 5900HX):
ratios=[7.547238551824045, 7.7139313128133695, 8.107636991904526, 8.47469155964413, 8.515605405050453, 9.172278506610215, 9.264749488149516, 9.557285255101801, 9.732214553686939, 10.802841012657689]
average_of_non_outlier_ratios=8.81729913412012
ratios=[8.762047219247435, 9.363372687067253, 10.145566544719255, 10.273140281551237, 10.487873752826854, 10.565872639113923, 10.64029167782034, 10.851233192929538, 10.912942606522284]
average_of_non_outlier_ratios=10.332478682289771
ratios=[8.382434555765164, 8.908493460199315, 9.066042017779642, 9.246098538177652, 9.304737133942659, 9.344529276678669, 9.546876520275672, 9.67229994476119, 9.823606780332556, 10.052732405298912, 10.14929796045462]
average_of_non_outlier_ratios=9.440601786382919
ratios=[7.803052242564962, 7.932774450890674, 8.347134115632969, 8.852060665356214, 8.994566905937972, 9.0039864187857, 9.498503106794697, 9.546413522518069, 9.691255389690461, 9.854593372412797, 9.937521780512633, 10.19999157374594]
average_of_non_outlier_ratios=9.165880972853216
ratios=[7.099565478498517, 8.512732314924916, 9.046465299081852, 9.084934322568525, 9.327585485547285, 9.338322586851053, 9.863004542840564, 10.110251878795596, 10.392818699806847, 10.751848197312722]
average_of_non_outlier_ratios=9.459514391302081
ratios=[8.368777843440359, 8.996354403223918, 9.304374924721822, 9.380879393237096, 9.64438818894823, 9.765254594302451, 10.050183387024001, 10.396627186085164, 10.611003799304875]
average_of_non_outlier_ratios=9.648294582506097

Each ratio in ratios is the minimum time across ten trials at size \$128\$ divided by the minimum time across ten trials at size \$64\$. Each run of trials stops when it does not appear that the next trial will finish within \$59\$ seconds of starting the run. The average of the ratios after discarding the minimum and maximum (average_of_non_outlier_ratios) is then displayed.
Yes, there is quite a large variance in the results, I'm not sure how to better measure this, but it looks like it's roughly \$8=2^3\$.

Looked at the reference implementation and I note that this implementation is doing much the same thing, but avoids checking divisibility for numbers higher than necessary. (I wish I'd looked earlier :D)

Is there a reason not to use @cache?

@Simd I originally wrote it with cache, but it is not available on TIO as it's 3.9+. I don't believe it should make a difference (although I am using 3.11 locally so not 100% sure).

@SophiaAntipolis I have made an improvement by caching divisors in pairs.

...oh, don't need pairs (never use d) will update. EDIT: done.

You can pull tree_count(i, max_height) out of the inner sum, and then extract the rest of the inner sum into it's own cached function of nodes - i and next_height. On my own computer this brings the ratio down to (6.8-10.9). TIO link in the next comment

TIO

@SophiaAntipolis the divisor functions should return a list instead of a generator since generators are consumed after they are iterated. For example, list(divisors(10)) will return [] the second time it is called

@gsitcia that's a good idea, thanks! The timings are so variable, I'm wondering if the ratios should be median / median...

There are two special cases that could be added: if nodes - 1 == max_height: return tree_count(nodes, nodes - 2) + max_height - 1; if nodes == max_height: return tree_count(nodes, nodes - 1) + 1.

@SophiaAntipolis nice idea, but it seems that the added overhead of the comparisons (performed for all but 1 node or 0 max height) outweighs the savings of the small number of pruned cases (since the pruned cases would be adding to the cache for those beneath anyway).

Maple, 161 bytes, ~9.8
Uncompressed:
div := n -> numtheory:-divisors(n):
PT := proc(n, k) option remember; local d, i;
   if n = 1 then ifelse(k > 0, 1, 0) else
   add(add(d * PT(i + 1, k) * PT(d, k - 1),
   d = div(n - i - 1)), i = 0..n - 2) / (n - 1) fi end:

Benchmark:
Tri := rows -> local n, k; seq(seq(PT(n, k), k=0..n), n=0..rows):

CodeTools:-Usage(Tri(64));
memory used=97.22MiB, alloc change=32.00MiB, 
cpu time=1.42s, real time=1.47s, gc time=0ns

CodeTools:-Usage(Tri(128));
memory used=1.02GiB, alloc change=97.00MiB, 
cpu time=14.03s, real time=14.26s, gc time=93.75ms

cpu: 14.03/1.42 ~ 9.8; 
real: 14.26/1.47 ~ 9.7;


Charcoal, 61 bytes, score ~9.4
Ｎθ⊞υ⟦⁰⟧Ｆθ⊞υＥ⊕θ∧κ∨¬ι÷ΣＥιΣＥ÷ι⊕μ××⊕ξ§§υ⊕ξ⊖κ§§υ⁻ι⊖×⊕ξ⊕μκιＥυ⭆¹…ι⊕κ

Try it online! Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation: Initially based on the reference implementation but using dynamic programming rather than recursion and memoisation, I replaced i with nodes - i and then switched the order of the double sum, allowing me to replace the inner loop with a stepped loop.
Before the last optimisation this code definitely exhibited O(n⁴) complexity and could only manage n=32 online. However if I Attempt This Online! I get timings of ~1s for n=16, ~4s for n=32 and ~32s for n=64, so this version might actually be better than that.
Edit: Testing locally, 10 runs for n=128 averaged out at 2.63 minutes each while 10 runs for n=64 averaged out at 0.28 minutes each, about 9.4 times faster.

What ratio do you get for the score?

@Simd Seems to be about 9.4 in my limited testing.

I did some more testing and came up with a figure of 9.248 times difference.

@SophiaAntipolis I think you can use sum(sum(i * polya_tree(n - i * j, n) * polya_tree(i, n - 1) for i in range(1, n // j)) for j in range(1, n)) // (n - 1), but that's from code inspection only.

C++ (gcc), 2222 bytes
#include <chrono>
#include <map>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <boost/multiprecision/cpp_int.hpp>

using bigint = boost::multiprecision::cpp_int;

std::map<int, std::vector<int>> divisor_cache;
std::map<std::pair<int, int>, bigint> tree_count_cache;

const std::vector<int>& divisors(int n) {
    if (divisor_cache.find(n) != divisor_cache.end()) {
        return divisor_cache[n];
    }

    std::vector<int> divisors;
    for (int d = 1; d <= n; ++d) {
        if (n % d == 0) {
            divisors.push_back(d);
        }
    }

    divisor_cache[n] = divisors;
    return divisor_cache[n];
}

bigint tree_count(int nodes, int max_height) {
    if (nodes == 1) {
        return max_height > 0 ? 1 : 0;
    }

    auto cache_key = std::make_pair(nodes, max_height);
    if (tree_count_cache.find(cache_key) != tree_count_cache.end()) {
        return tree_count_cache[cache_key];
    }

    int next_height = max_height - 1;
    bigint total = 0;

    for (int i = 1; i < nodes; ++i) {
        for (const auto& d : divisors(nodes - i)) {
            total += tree_count(i, max_height) * d * tree_count(d, next_height);
        }
    }

    total /= (nodes - 1);
    tree_count_cache[cache_key] = total;
    return total;
}

std::pair<double, std::vector<bigint>> measure(int size) {
    using namespace std;
    using namespace std::chrono;

    divisor_cache.clear();
    tree_count_cache.clear();

    auto start = steady_clock::now();

    vector<bigint> table;
    table.reserve(size * (size + 1) / 2);

    for (int n = 0; n < size; ++n) {
        for (int h = 0; h <= n; ++h) {
            table.push_back(tree_count(n, h));
        }
    }

    auto end = steady_clock::now();
    duration<double> elapsed = end - start;

    std::cout << size << ": " << elapsed.count() << " seconds" << std::endl;
    return { elapsed.count(), table };
}

int main() {
    int size = 64;
    auto [time_taken_1, table_1] = measure(size);
    auto [time_taken_2, table_2] = measure(size * 2);

    std::cout << "Ratio: " << time_taken_2 / time_taken_1 << "\n[";

    // Print the table values
    for (const auto& val : table_2) {
        std::cout << val << ", ";
    }
    std::cout << "]\n";

    return 0;
}

Try it online!
C++ port of Jonathan Allan's answer. The ratio looks about same:
64: 0.115634 seconds
64: 0.116452 seconds
64: 0.114451 seconds
64: 0.118066 seconds
64: 0.118879 seconds
64: 0.117783 seconds
64: 0.116525 seconds
64: 0.117978 seconds
64: 0.116567 seconds
64: 0.117778 seconds
128: 1.38461 seconds
128: 1.40242 seconds
128: 1.39773 seconds
128: 1.41565 seconds
128: 1.36205 seconds
128: 1.36052 seconds
128: 1.38965 seconds
128: 1.38398 seconds
128: 1.34887 seconds
128: 1.32237 seconds
Ratio: 11.7663


Rust
Run it on Rust playground!
// Cargo.toml
// [package]
// name = "polya_trees_count"
// version = "0.1.0"
// edition = "2021"

// # See more keys and their definitions at https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html

// [dependencies]
// num-bigint = "0.4"
// num-traits = "0.2"


// [profile.release]
// lto = "y"
// panic = "abort"

// $ cargo build --release
// $ cargo run   --release

use std::collections::HashMap;
use std::time::Instant;
use num_bigint::BigInt;
use num_traits::One;

type BigIntCache = HashMap<(i32, i32), BigInt>;
type DivisorCache = HashMap<i32, Vec<i32>>;

fn divisors(n: i32, cache: &mut DivisorCache) -> Vec<i32> {
    if let Some(divs) = cache.get(&n) {
        return divs.clone();
    }

    let mut divs = Vec::new();
    for d in 1..=n {
        if n % d == 0 {
            divs.push(d);
        }
    }

    cache.insert(n, divs.clone());
    divs
}

fn tree_count(nodes: i32, max_height: i32, cache: &mut BigIntCache, divisor_cache: &mut DivisorCache) -> BigInt {
    if nodes == 1 {
        return if max_height > 0 { BigInt::one() } else { BigInt::from(0) };
    }

    if let Some(count) = cache.get(&(nodes, max_height)) {
        return count.clone();
    }

    let next_height = max_height - 1;
    let mut total = BigInt::from(0);

    for i in 1..nodes {
        for &d in &divisors(nodes - i, divisor_cache) {
            total += tree_count(i, max_height, cache, divisor_cache) * BigInt::from(d) * tree_count(d, next_height, cache, divisor_cache);
        }
    }

    total /= BigInt::from(nodes - 1);
    cache.insert((nodes, max_height), total.clone());
    total
}

fn measure(size: usize) -> (f64, Vec<BigInt>) {
    let mut divisor_cache = DivisorCache::new();
    let mut tree_count_cache = BigIntCache::new();

    let start = Instant::now();
    let mut table = Vec::with_capacity(size * (size + 1) / 2);

    for n in 0..size as i32 {
        for h in 0..=n {
            table.push(tree_count(n, h, &mut tree_count_cache, &mut divisor_cache));
        }
    }

    let elapsed = start.elapsed();
    println!("{}: {} seconds", size, elapsed.as_secs_f64());
    (elapsed.as_secs_f64(), table)
}


fn main() {
    let size = 64;
    let (time_taken_1, _table_1) = measure(size);
    let (time_taken_2, table_2) = measure(size * 2);

    println!("Ratio: {}", time_taken_2 / time_taken_1);
    print!("[");
    for val in &table_2 {
        print!("{}, ", val);
    }
    println!("]");
}

Rust port of Jonathan Allan's answer. The ratio looks about same:
64: 0.0767605 seconds
128: 0.8220573 seconds
Ratio: 10.709379172881887

64: 0.0745293 seconds
128: 0.824322 seconds
Ratio: 11.060374912953696

64: 0.0759358 seconds
128: 0.881342 seconds
Ratio: 11.606409624972674


Wolfram Language (Mathematica), ~8.49784
Clear["Global`*"];
(*Define the divisors function*)div[n_Integer?Positive] := Divisors[n]

(*Define the PT function with memoization*)
PT[0, 0] := 0;
PT[n_Integer?Positive, k_Integer?NonNegative] := 
 PT[n, k] = 
  If[n == 1, 
   If[k > 0, 1, 
    0], (Sum[
      Sum[d*PT[i + 1, k]*PT[d, k - 1], {d, div[n - i - 1]}], {i, 0, 
       n - 2}])/(n - 1)]
Table[PT[n, k], {n, 0, 64}, {k, 0, n}] // Grid // AbsoluteTiming //Print (* 0.744101 seconds on my laptop *)
Table[PT[n, k], {n, 0, 128}, {k, 0, n}] // Grid // AbsoluteTiming //Print (* 6.02482 seconds on my laptop *)

Try it online!
